# Is making a iVar public in objective C defeats the purpose of encapsulation?

Tags: objective-c, oop

Is making a iVar public in objective-C defeats the purpose of encapsulation?

```
@interface SampleClass{
@public
int totalRecords;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, yes.

Direct access of ivars means that there is no way that subclasses or future versions of your `SampmleClass` can ever implement any kind of customized behavior when `totalRecords` is read or written.

This is why access to object state is through methods everywhere but in the implementation of the class itself (and, even then, it is mostly through methods).